# Lightning component not available in app builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, app-builder

I have created a lightning component shell that I want to make available to the lightning app builder so I can drop the component into a new lightning app that I created. When I got to app manager and under select items I do not see the lightning component. When I created the lightning bundle, I added all the elements of the bundle, cmp, controller, helper, renderer, svg, design. Here is my component shell:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

</aura:component>
```

My domain is enabled. What else is needed in order to make the component available to select from the app builder?

Nothing  has been added to the component yet. It's just a shell at the moment.

Comment: Are you doing this within a community? If so, you are missing: forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes

Comment: its the lightning app builder =P

Comment: Ah... completely overlooked that part :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just need to refresh your App Builder interface. Normally, with what you have,  it should be available under custom components on your left hand panel.

[image]

What you have should work.

Comment: Okay, strange, I logged out and then logged back in and now it is there. I guess a refresh is what I needed. Thanks!